# Class representing any value. Type should be hidden but type should be comparable

Tags: generics, swift

I want to build a structure like in a blackboard where the type of a value is wrapped so that the `BlackboardValue` can be passed around without restriction of the type it actually holds.

Secondly I need to check if two `BlackboardValue`s hold a value of the same type.
Using `BlackboardValue<T>` won't work as it seems since `BlackboardValue<String>` can't be stored alongside `BlackboardValue<Double>` and other problems. `BlackboardValue` should be a single type.

I think the problem can be reduced to the fact that I seem to be unable to check if two Wrappers hold the same type:

```
import Foundation

class Wrapper {
    var value: Any?

    init(v: Any) {
        self.value = v
    }
}

func wrappersHoldTheSameValueType(w1: Wrapper, w2: Wrapper) -> Bool {
    return false
}

var w = Wrapper(v: "Hans")
var d = w.value as String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do it. Try this way.

```
func wrappersHoldTheSameValueType(w1: Wrapper, w2: Wrapper) -> Bool {
    let typeidof = { (a: Any) in
        unsafeBitCast(reflect(a).valueType, uintptr_t.self)
    }
    switch ((w1.value, w2.value)) {
        case let (.Some(a), .Some(b)):
            return typeidof(a) == typeidof(b)
        case (nil, nil):
            return true
        default:
            return false
    }
}
```

Somewhat awkward, but seems work at least for now.

```
wrappersHoldTheSameValueType(Wrapper(v:1), Wrapper(v:2))         // ==> true
wrappersHoldTheSameValueType(Wrapper(v:"a"), Wrapper(v:"b"))     // ==> true
wrappersHoldTheSameValueType(Wrapper(v:["a"]), Wrapper(v:["b"])) // ==> true
wrappersHoldTheSameValueType(Wrapper(v:UIView()), Wrapper(v:1))  // ==> false
wrappersHoldTheSameValueType(Wrapper(v:[1]), Wrapper(v:["a"]))   // ==> false
```

Comment: I will accept the answer as it works. But i think alot of people will be happy if this information will be updated when someone finds a "cleaner" solution. But yes, it works for all types i tried.

Comment: Since you seem to have a deeper understanding of the inner works: Do you have an idea how to compare a wrapper (its value) and a Type like isOfType( value, type ) -> Bool .. ?

Comment: I've added little commentary in the above page.